# как очистить индекс

Tags: git

Алгоритм действий:

1. Сначала я добавил в проект  папку с большим количеством файлов
2. Потом добавил их в индекс `git add .`, но при этом забыл создать файл `.gitignore` и в него же прописать список игнорируемых файлов

   ```
   vendor/
   npm/
   some_folder/
   и т.д.
   ```

есть ряд папок, которые надо убрать из индекса, но они уже попали в индекс, а `git status`  выдает

```
(use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
```

Обычно доводилось делать `git reset HEAD .` для всех и сразу,  а  такое у меня впервые. Как же сразу убрать все файлы (в том числе и вложенные) из индекса?

Comment: `git read-tree --empty`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как же сразу убрать все файлы (в том числе и вложенные) из индекса

программа же подсказывает:

> ```
> (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
> ```

а для рекурсивного удаления надо добавить опцию `-r` (о чём сама же программа *git* и напомнит, если ввести команду без неё):

```
$ git rm -r --cached .
```

а можно указать и не весь текущий каталог (`.`), а конкретный(-е) файл(ы)/каталог(и):

```
$ git rm -r --cached каталог1 каталог2 файл ...
```

Answer (score 1):

git filter-branch --force (чтобы не удалился каталог с жесткого диска)

git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -rf PATH" HEAD

где PATH - путь к файлу/папке

https://toster.ru/q/176843

https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository